# HQL / Postgres : ERROR: operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer

Tags: postgresql, hql

I am trying to familiarise myself with Hql, Postgres and JDBC queries. I have a simple query to retrieve records from a table that were modified in last week :

```
String query = "SELECT t.id FROM table t"
        + " WHERE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP <= t.last_modified_timestamp + 7";
```

but getting this exception:

> nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator
> does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer

Did I miss something? I probably missed the right command to do so.

Comment: +7 what? Years, months, days, weeks, seconds? You need an INTERVAL for this, like INTERVAL '7 DAYS'

Comment: Note that in order for the database to be able to use an index on `last_modified_timestamp` you need to rephrase this to `t.last_modified_timestamp >= current_timestamp - interval '7 days'`